# How turn off CustomLog on apache2 for Windows?

Tags: apache, apache2

I'm using apache2 server on windows server, and there is a lot website config. I already open the CustomLog(access log) on httpd.conf global setting.

But now I just want to turn off the log just for 1 web site. like:

```
<VirtualHost 17.100.18.18:80>  
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
    ServerName 17.100.18.18

    //disable log on here

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to add `CustomLog Off`, but not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the log for only 1 web site. you need set it like this:

```
<VirtualHost 17.100.18.18:80>  
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
    ServerName 17.100.18.18
```

> **CustomLog C:/nul common**

```
</VirtualHost>
```

The answer from :http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=18028